# Persistently naming an unformatted partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

**In brief**: is there a way to give a persistent name to an unformatted partition?

**Details**: I have a database-like application that reads and writes to an unformatted partition (because it gives me a 40% throughput boost compared to when writing to a regular file). The name of the file that I open is /dev/sda3.

I recently found out that the names of devices may change across boots. This is because these names are assigned to these devices numerically in the order they are discovered by the bootloader. Changes are uncommon in a stable environment, but I've observed them occurring. They may lead one to accidentally write data to the wrong partition thereby corrupting it. Maintainability also becomes a hassle, since I have to constantly verify I am writing to the correct device.

The way to solve this is usually to use [persistent device names](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming). However, it seems like one cannot create a persistent name for an unformatted partition. I tried the command: "tune2fs -L newname /dev/sda3", but I get these errors:

> tune2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013) tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block
>
> while trying to open /dev/sda3 Couldn't find valid filesystem
>
> superblock.

So, is there any way of at least achieving the same effect as giving a persistent name to an unformatted partition? Thanks!

Comment: Your application has no way to identify or mark its data areas other than the device name its given? Sounds primitive!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking how to do, Kreemoweet. How would you do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you're using a GPT partition table

The GPT partition table stores a unique partition GUID in the [partition entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries_(LBA_2-33)). So you can access the partition using `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/whatever` instead of `/dev/sdXY`

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid
```

(Tested on Ubuntu 18)

### If you're using a MBR allocation table

You can access a drive partition by using the drive serial number and partition number `/dev/disk/by-id/whatever-partY` instead of `/dev/sdXY`

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
```

(Tested on Ubuntu 18)

However, as with /dev/sdXY, the risk is that if you create/delete a partition on this disk, the partition number may change and you risk to overwrite data on this disk. Both the partition label and UUID are stored within the filesystem, so if you don't use a filesystem, you give the system no way to eliminate the risk of writing on the wrong partition.

But at least, that way, you can be confident that it's the right disk.

---

NB: These paths are accessible as long as the system is booted. During the boot process (ie. if you're using initramfs hook and boot scripts to do weird stuff), this path has a slighly different naming convention.